# cypress deal with decimal places

Tags: cypress

[image]

i am trying to sum all table column values and total of the values must be 1.
as shown in the image value the actual total of values is 1, but it is showing 1.0000000000000000000002.
i didn't getting where it is going wrong. i take the values from json file and values are same in json file as well. it must be error with decimal places. how to deal with this.

```
var sum = 0 
  var expectedSum=1


  cy.get('td :nth-child(3) > input:visible').each(($el, index, $list) => {

    // var result =parseFloat($el.val())
  var result =$el.val()
  sum=Number(sum)+Number(result)
  cy.log(result)

  }).then(function()
  {
    cy.log('allocation total:'+sum)
    //assertion to check total alocation percent is 100
    expect(sum).to.equal(expectedSum)
  })
```

Comment: that a problem with js as a language, not the cypress, in your case you need to round the result before test. you might not know that ```0.3+0.2 !== 0.5 //true``` in js :)

Comment: @alexnikonov is it possible without changing the test data?

Comment: i dont think so, but may be you may use toFixed ```(0.4+0.2).toFixed(2) === 0.60``` and for your example it will be ```expect(sum.toFixed(3)).to.equal(expectedSum)``` depending on you precision needs

Answer (score 1):

Check that the difference is below a certain threshold.

From the log it looks like your numbers are no more than 3 decimals, so

```js
expect(Math.abs(1 - sum)).to.be.below(0.001)
```