# Rounding in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, rounding, tofixed

I want to compare a number from a form to a set number. The issue is that we have dozens of different systems and depending on the system the number can be displayed with 2 to 4 decimal places. So in one system the number is displayed as 11,1265, in another as 11,127 and in yet another as 11,13. Therefore I would like to found the number to decimal places before the assertion.

I have already found this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61928723/cypress-deal-with-decimal-places) and and tried to implement the solution. Could not get it to work though as Cypress does not know `.toFixed()`

This is what I have tried so far:

1. From answer [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61928723/cypress-deal-with-decimal-places)

```js
cy.get('#Client_rate_ap').then(res => {
                expect(res.toFixed(2)).to.equal('11,13')
})
```

This returns

```
TypeError
res.toFixed is not a function
```

2. with cy.wrap()

```js
 cy.get('#Client_rate_ap').then(res => {
                cy.wrap(res).toFixed(2).should('be.equal','11,13')
            })
```

and

```js
 cy.get('#Client_rate_ap').then(res => {
                cy.wrap(res.toFixed(2)).should('be.equal','11,13')
            })
```

Both also return the error `toFixed is not a function`

{{edit}} Added element

This is the element with the value that I want to compare:

```html
<input class="rate_ap tariff-connected-field" name="Client[rate_ap]" id="Client_rate_ap" type="text" value="11,1300">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first convert your text to float and then apply `.toFixed(2)`. Something like:

```js
cy.get('#Client_rate_ap')
  .invoke('val')
  .then((rate) => {
    expect(parseFloat(rate).toFixed(2)*1).to.equal(11.13)
  })
```

In case your prices are displayed in comma, then first you have to replace the comma with a decimal, in that case you can:

```js
cy.get('#Client_rate_ap')
  .invoke('val')
  .then((rate) => {
    expect(parseFloat(rate.replace(',', '.')).toFixed(2)*1).to.equal(11.13)
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was pretty far away from the solution. Unfortunately Cypress tells me ```TypeError
rate.replace is not a function```when I try the 2nd solution (as our prices are indeed displayed with commas)

Comment: can you log rate using `cy.log(rate)`, it should display the price string. And also please add the html for one of the element having the rate text.

Comment: Added the html element in the original question and just realized it is stored as a value there not a text. Guess I need some kind of ```.invoke(value)``` command.

{{edit}}When I ```cy.log(rate)``` I get ```<input#Client_rate_ap.rate_ap.tariff-connected-field>
```

Comment: Yes you are correct than you have to use `invoke('val')` and this should work now. You can still keep the `cy.log(rate)` to check if you are getting the string or not.

Comment: Correct. This works perfectly! Thanks a ton

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does the ```*1```do behind ```toFixed(2)```?

Comment: `toFixed(2)` returns a string value. `toFixed(2)*1` will convert it into a number.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way using the answer you already found,

```js
cy.get('#Client_rate_ap')
  .then(res => {
    expect(Math.abs(11.13 - res.replace(',','.'))).to.be.below(0.01)
  })
})
```